# Does React not explicitly export forwardRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATE: There is nothing wrong with the implementation below. The error was due to a react-redux upgrade, as redux now relies on functional components instead of class components.

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

const DivWithRef = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return(
    <div ref={ref} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
})
```

```
class AClassComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DivWithRef ref={me => this.node = me} />
    ) 
  }
}
```

When I try this I get the error:

```sh
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. 
Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Does react not explicitly export forwardRef?

I have been using this code for a while, and it never caused any issues. After I updated to React 16.8, I started getting the warning above, but my app can still access the DOM Ref even though react claims it shouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered it on my own. It's not a problem with my implementation. Callback refs are a valid implementation, as explained here: [reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs](http://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

The reason for the error is that the latest version of react-redux uses functional components instead of class components. After I updated to react-redux, my refs on connected components return the error.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do this instead:

```
constructor() {
  this.node = React.createRef();
}
// more code
render() {
  return <DivWithRef ref={this.node} />;
}
```

The rest of your code is correct.

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: Callback refs are a valid way to write refs. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

Answer (score 0):

The second ref argument only exists when you define a component with React.forwardRef call.

[React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: The example on the page you linked to looks almost exactly like my component

Comment: You need to creatRef first as described by @Josep.

Comment: No you actually don't. There's something called callback refs which is a valid implementation.